# Internet Explorer 8 Redirect Issue

Tags: spring, internet-explorer

I have made a JSP page which send request to @controller into method UserList() and displayes data using Jquery AJAX. I have applied paging concept into this and on Click of an hyperLink "NEXT" and "PREVIOUS" I send request to method next() in controller which increases or decreases the size of page on every request and redirects back to userList() to get data after the current increased/decreased page value.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "next")
public String next(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
       ++userListPage;
       return "redirect:/admin/userList";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "userList")
public String userList(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) throws Exception {

    data is retrived over here and response is send back to JSP
}
```

This works fine in chrome , firefox but not working in Internet Explorer 8.
When I click "NEXT" on JSP first time the next() redirects to the UserList() but after again for second time i Click on "NEXT" the next() wont redirect to the UserList() method but instead for that it consider return "redirect:/admin/userList"; as view name and view is got resolved. 
I have tried a lot but nothing works .Please Help me for this.
Thanks In Adv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
return "forward:/admin/userList";
```

Because IE8 sends request to client and this time client don't send request to server. Therefor it is not working for u.

Comment: I don't think that your explanation is correct . But Still thanks For Your answer it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where I submitted a form from the browser via a POST request. In the controller method configured to handle the POST, after performing the necessary processing I was trying to redirect to another controller method (configured for a GET). It worked in Firefox and Chrome, but not in IE. Even after changing the return view of the first controller from from redirect to forward, it did not seem to work in IE. The issue was that forward uses the same request method scope ie POST in this example, so I had to remove the request method GET specified on the second controller method for this to work.